# Android build apk Invalid code lengths set

Tags: android, gradle, build, apk

I am trying to build apk but each time i got this :

```
Cause: invalid code lengths set
```

I have another project but i can build it.

My Gradle version :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
```

How should i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a zip (jar) error message; so delete all caches and build again.